# OpenCV cv::Mat "+="inside for loop

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a simple ghost-trail effect in C++. I am adding `cv::Mat` images into a `std::vector`, I have a function that can access the images, change opacity & add two together, which works:

```
void ghostEffect(std::vector<cv::Mat> &srcImages, cv::Mat &dstImage)
{
    static int currFrame = 0;
    dstImage = srcImages[currFrame%srcImages.size]*0.5+srcImages[(currFrame+1)%srcImages.size]*0.5;
    currFrame++;
}
```

I would like to use a for() loop to iterate over many images in the vector, however when I do I get a seg fault. Wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
void ghostEffect(std::vector<cv::Mat> &srcImages, cv::Mat &dstImage)
{
    static int currFrame = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < srcImages.size; i++)
    {
        dstImage += srcImages[(currFrame+i)%srcImages.size]*(1/srcImages.size);
    }
    currFrame++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is strange. It should not be compiled. `std::vector::size` is a method, thus your loop compares `i` with the address of the method `std::vector::size`, which may be much bigger than the vector size.

Also result of the expression `1/srcImages.size()` is always zero if the vector size is greater then 1, since arguments of int type produces int type.

I suppose you have to code the function like bellow:

```
void ghostEffect(std::vector<cv::Mat> &srcImages, cv::Mat &dstImage)
{
    static int currFrame = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < srcImages.size(); i++)
    {
        dstImage += srcImages[(currFrame+i)%srcImages.size()]*(1.0/srcImages.size());
    }
    currFrame++;
}
```

The first snippet is working by a lucky coincidence until `currFrame` exceeds the vector size. Replace `srcImages.size` with `srcImages.size()` too.

Comment: Thanks @S.M. This fixed the function, but I was still getting an error, worked out that I wasn't populating the vector<cv::Mat> with blank images to start with. So now just did: 

     for(uint i = 0; i<queSize; i++)
        cameraFrames[i]= Mat::zeros(cameraFrames[0].size(), cameraFrames[0].type());

Also made a variable for QueSize so I don't need to call a method every time I need to get size of the vector.